# How to set priority on routes using Graphhopper

Tags: java, graphhopper

I am currently using graphhopper to build a navigation system for a park. Within the park, there are two types of routes and when the weather is bad, one type of route should be set with higher priority during navigation. How could I approach to solve this problem. I realised there is something called priority in the foot flag encoder but I have no idea how to make use of it.

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicates on SO and on our forum or explicitely cross-link the created entries: https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-to-set-higher-priority-for-routes-with-certain-tags/1616